# Symfony 3 - Doctrine Validations and User roles

Tags: symfony, validation, doctrine, roles

I have a `file` property in my entity and I want to define different `maxfilesize` constraints, depending on user role.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you have so far? General questions like this, are likely to get closed here in Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section for more details

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom constraint as a service and inject AuthorizationCheckerInterface to it:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html

Comment: Please do not answer **too broad** questions.